# pandas grouping based on different data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group data based on different dataframe's cuts.

So for instance I cut from a frame:

```
my_fcuts = pd.qcut(frame1['prices'],5)

pd.groupby(frame2, my_fcuts)
```

Since the lengths must be same, the above statement will fail.

I know I can easily write a mapper function, but what if this was the case

my_fcuts = pd.qcut(frame1['prices'],20) or some higher number. Surely there must be some built-in statement in pandas to do this very simple thing. groupby should be able to accept "cuts" from different data and reclassify.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show sample data with the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I figured out the answer myself

```
volgroups = np.digitize(btest['vol_proxy'],np.linspace(min(data['vol_proxy']), max(data['vol_proxy']), 10))
trendgroups = np.digitize(btest['trend_proxy'],np.linspace(min(data['trend_proxy']), max(data['trend_proxy']), 10))

#btest.groupby([volgroups,trendgroups]).mean()['pnl'].plot(kind='bar')
#plt.show()

df = btest.groupby([volgroups,trendgroups]).groups
```